# Password Expiration Time CS4

Tags: flash-cs4

I have a password-protected website in Flash CS4. I want to make so that if someone submits the password and leaves, he won't have to do it again if he returns within x time. Do you have any ideas how such things can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashCookie/index.html

Set a cookie that saves that they are logged in!